# Laravel Blade Display with Dynamic Columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have a successful database query in my controller using DB::select that gives me a nice array of results which I have verified. I'd like to arrange it in the view, such that I can look at the months sorted by data and also a set of dynamic columns in the database by a particular portfolio. I am able to hard-code the values in the blade, but obviously that is not going to work for dynamic columns.

I've provided the code and also done some extra mysql queries to no avail. I've read countless posts in the forums and didn't see anything applicable, so I figured I would post.

```
$monthly_paid = DB::select('select year(date) as year, month(date) as month, sum(payment_amount) as total_monthly, p.portfolio_name as portfolio, 
payment_amount, paid from funds
join portfolios as p where funds.portfolio_id = p.id and hide = 0
group by year(date), month(date), portfolio');
dd($monthly_paid);
```

The query results:

```
array:12 [▼
0 => {#217 ▼
+"year": 2018
+"month": 1
+"total_monthly": 2900.0
+"portfolio": "TW-CS"
+"payment_amount": "2900"
+"paid": 1
} ... etc.
```

Here is my blade attempt:

```
 @foreach ($monthly_paid as $monthly)
        <div class="row">
                <?php $monthNum = $monthly->month;
                        $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
                        $monthName = $dateObj->format('F');?>
                <div class="col-md-1">{{ $monthly->year }}</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">{{ $monthName }}</div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                @if($monthly->portfolio == "TW-CS")
                @if($monthly->paid == 1)
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                        ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                </button>
                @else
                ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                @endif
                @endif
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                @if($monthly->portfolio == "TW-C12")
                @if($monthly->paid == 1)
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                        ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                </button>
                @else
                ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                @endif
                @endif
 </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                @if($monthly->portfolio == "TW-C22")
                @if($monthly->paid == 1)
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                        ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                </button>
                @else
                ${{ number_format($monthly->payment_amount) }}
                @endif
                @endif
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF;">${{ number_format($monthly->total_monthly) }}</div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

I am trying to get the following format:

```
    TW-CS     TW-C12    TW-C22    TOTAL AMOUNT PAID
    $7500     $7800     $8200     $23,500
```

The first column is the month, second column is portfolio 1, third column is portfolio 2, fourth column is portfolio 3 and the final column is the sum.

Obviously, hard-coded, it displays properly, but I am trying to automate it.

Comment: In your controller, try duplicating your query but adding the ->toArray() method. Then you can do a foreach to put all the "portfolios" into an array and pass that array to your view. In your view, you can do a foreach that loops through the portfolio names. This way, no matter what the portfolio names are, or how many you have, you'll always be generating the view dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, it is already an array. I think my confusion is the portfolio names being the columns in the blade and dynamic.

Comment: Your array is coming back mixed hence the + icon . You require setting variable $monthly_paid to key [0] to use as array I believe. Not tested but usually the issue.

Comment: Thanks. The data is reaching the blade fine. The issue is displaying it as I had described. I can write a simple nested loop and show any information availabble. I gave the comtroller and array sample as merely a background.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you can get a Dynamic Column form Dynamic Model. as well as its Models Relation too

> For Model

```
public function  scopeCustomSelect( $query ,$items=[])
{
    $stu_class_col=['id as stu_class_id','std_id']; // Required else retional model will not retun data. here id and std_id is primary key and foreign key.
    $stu_doc_col=['id as stu_doc_id','std_id'];// Required else retional model will not retun data. here id and std_id is primary key and foreign key.

    foreach ( $items as $col)
    {
        if(  Schema::hasColumn('student_information', $col ))
        {
          $stu_info_col[]= $col ;
        }
        elseif (  Schema::hasColumn('student_class',$col))
        {
            $stu_class_col[]= $col ;
        }
        elseif (  Schema::hasColumn('student_image',$col))
        {
            $stu_doc_col[]= $col ;
        }
    }
// converting array to string for bind column into with relation...
    $stu_class_col_string =  implode(',',$stu_class_col);
    $stu_doc_col_string =  implode(',',$stu_doc_col); 

    return $colQuery = $query->select($stu_info_col)
                    ->with(["student_class:$stu_class_col_string", "studentImage:$stu_doc_col_string"]);
}
```

> For Controller

```
 $studentInfo =  Student::whereHas("student_class",function($q) use($req){
                                   $q->where("std_session",$req->session_code);
                                   $q ->where("std_class",$req->class_code);
                                   $q ->where("std_section",$req->std_section); })
                           ->customSelect($fields['dataList'])
                           ->get();
```